# calculate program execution time in embedded device from python code

Tags: microcontroller, cpu-architecture, nodemcu, flops

I have a python program which I want to deploy in an MCU. Before selecting an MCU for this task, i want to estimate the absolute base requirements for the MCU. On a M1 pro chip the self CPU execution time is 231.259ms and used memory is 16mb. How do I find out the number of instructions executed in python and how much time it will need to execute the program in an MCU?

Comment: *the number of instructions executed in python* - Easy, use a profiling tool to have the CPU's performance counters record it, `perf stat --all-user  python ./foo.py` if you're running Linux on your M1, otherwise a MacOS equivalent.  *how much time it will need to execute the program in an MCU* - Near impossible to predict with any accuracy.  There isn't a fixed cost per instruction you can just add up, unless your CPU is so simple and low-end it doesn't have cache or pipelined execution.  If you're planning to use an AArch64 chip, that's unlikely.  If a Cortex-M, pretty low-end for Python...

Comment: `If a Cortex-M, pretty low-end for Python` what do you mean by this? I dont need accurate estimation just a ballpark, is there any other way to estimate if the .py program will run on an mcu?

Comment: I mean a CPU with no cache and no pipelining of load latency, such as Cortex-M, where each instruction pretty much has a fixed cost in cycles you can just add up (for a given choice of DRAM and flash speeds and thus wait-states), that would be pretty slow for running Python.  And you normally couldn't run an OS on it, so it might be hard to get Python to run at all.

Comment: You might get an order-of-magnitude estimate from an instruction count and an assumption of some IPC that makes sense for the CPU, like maybe near 1.0 for a 2-wide in-order CPU capable of running 2 instructions per clock, but stalling on cache misses, and with data dependencies limiting the ability to run more than 1 per clock.

Comment: It's pretty useless to compare the M1 Python interpreter with any Python interpreter for embedded devices (e.g. MicroPython). Besides the fact that using Python for embedded programming is using the wrong tool, the final execution time depends on the interpreter used. A NodeMCU is an ESP8266 which has a very limited amount of memory and power, so the embedded interpreter won't be as optimized as the M1 one. Beggars can't be choosers.  Also a NodeMCU is less than 5$, the best way to find this out is buy one and test the script.